# What is filmy, film in German?

Tags: translation

Just curious, not in the cinematographic sense but the thin and translucent sense, is there a word for that?

Comment: maybe give an example sentence?  `that dress is so light and filmy?`

Answer (score 7):

The German word for a very thin layer is the same as the English:

> Film

It is a loanword, that was imported into German in 19<sup>th</sup> century from English.

The thin layer was the first meaning, the next meaning was the thin layer that was used to capture pictures in cameras, and the third meaning was the movie that you could watch in a cinema.

Comment: The German Film does however not have an adjective. You would need to use "hauchdünn" or something similar.

Comment: It's a loa**n**word. ?

Comment: Any missing adjective to a substantive can be built with *-artig* in German. So, you could be using *filmartig*.

Comment: "Filmy" is *hauchdünn* in German, whereas *filmartig* translates as "film-like". See dictionaries.

Answer (score 5):

Beware of the false friend *[Film](https://dwds.de/wb/Film)* in German. This loanword from English is when used outside of a cinematographic/photographic context or in the name of *Tesafilm/Klebefilm* (transparent adhesive tape) almost exclusively used for a (mostly oily) **liquid covering**.

> Zum Schutz wird die Haut mit einem öligen Film überzogen.
>   Die Schrift war von einem Schmutzfilm verdeckt.

For all other English meanings, including adjectives we have different expressions which depend on the context they are used:

> **film:** *Folie, Klarsichtfolie, Schicht, Häutchen, Haut, Belag, Überzug, ...*
>   **filmy:** *zart, dünn, hauchdünn, durchsichtig, ...*

Comment: Im Prinzip hast Du Recht (daher auch upvote), aber man sollte den (das?) Tesafilm nicht vergessen - wenn der ölig ist, würde ich einen neuen Streifen nehmen...

Comment: @Volker Da hat sich in der Tat Dank von Anfang an der "Klebefilm" für ein transparentes (!) Klebeband eingebürgert. Witzigerweise heißt es im Englischen wiederum nicht *film* sondern *tape*.

Answer (score 1):

The adjective **filmy** has the defintions

> very thin and often transparent ––
>   examples: filmy material; 
>   a filmy dress
>   ––– Synonyms: 
>   diaphanous (literary) –
>   gossamer (literary) –
>   sheer
>   <sub>[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/de/worterbuch/englisch/filmy)</sub>

This gives us a few options to transport the meaning into German, which has *Film* as well, with largely the same meaning as in English, but not *filmy* or *filmig* in that sense. The word exists in German, but it had initially a very different meaning and language level:

> Jemand, der breit von Drogen ist, ist [filmig](https://www.mundmische.de/bedeutung/31498-filmig).  –– Someone inebriated by drugs is *filmig*. (Possiibly a development from *[Film fahren](https://www.mundmische.de/bedeutung/13266-Film_fahren)*)

But that seems to change right now. *Filmig* in the sense of "like a movie" is in use now as well:

> <sub>–– [und waren](https://ask.fm/kdvrnslwj/best?page=27) dann planlos draußen hahah in baumheide 
>   Plötzlich Pfeifen irgendwelche uns hinterher wir sind so gelaufen wie 2 Hunde, richtig gerannt und haben uns dann Taxi bestellt und wir warten.. Warten.... Und so nach 15 Minuten warten rufen wir da nochmal an und erfahren dass wir die falsche Adresse gegeben haben.. Boah war das Filmig, haben im Endeffekt bei ner Freundin geschlafen.   –– 
>  –– [Hatte heute](http://koenigquasi.tumblr.com/) “Überlandfahrt”
>   4 h über die Landstrasse geballert, war filmig</sub>

Currently this seems still confined to the language of teenagers and other sociolects. Wait a bit longer to find this in the [Duden](http://duden.de/) as well. It's a nice addition and the meaning easy to grasp for people not yet familiar with this word and its meaning.

Coming from a Cambridge definition the options would be:
***transparent, transluzent, hauchdünn, zart, duftig, trüb, diaphan, transluzid, durchsichtig (compare [dict.cc](https://www.dict.cc/englisch-deutsch/filmy.html)) und seltsamerweise auch als [häutchenartig](https://de.langenscheidt.com/englisch-deutsch/filmy), mit einem Häutchen bedeckt***

Additionally there is a nice German compound word: ***filmartig***

But the [urban dictionary defines filmy as](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=filmy):

> To be covered in grime often caused by sweating ––
>   Jess why are you so filmy? Have you been rolling in dirt all day?

That would make it possible to translate filmy *to schwitzig, verschwitzt, ölig* etc.

Comment: I've never heard the word "filmig" and Duden doesn't know it either.

Comment: @Iris Thx, I forgot the link.

Comment: @Iris Just asked an older co-worker: "Hab ich noch nie gehört"– (Erklärung mit Drogen, Spülmittelrestfilm, ) "Ach so, ja!"– (Pause) "Ich möchte aber auch nicht, dass das Wort existiert". Hab's persönlich in der Tram gehört. Teenies über Hanferfahrungen.